# Session killed in ASP .NET MVC application due to exception from C#-Dll?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, dll, exception, session-variables

In my ASP .NET MVC-Application I call functions of a c#-DLL. Sometimes the DLL throws an exception. In my code the exception is caught and handled. However, after that the session of the user, who has made the respective request, seems to be timed out.

Does Exceptions from Dlls cause ASP .NET MVC to clear the session, regardless whether they are handled or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, an Exception does not in general cause the session to be cleared.

Of course, the DLL could be explicitly clearing the session before propagating the exception.

Comment: not true. See Rapid Fail Protection inside the IIS, Maximum Failures.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found out the error: During the execution of my controller I wrote some statistics in a file in the bin folder of my application... That's why the session variables were cleared.

So, actually it had nothing to do with exceptions.

Comment: see also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849576/mvc3-session-timeout-after-10-seconds